# Android actionbar text trimmed

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I have the following action bar it just doesn't display the whole text on tabs
what's wrong with it?

```
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.tip).setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.manually_locate_yourself).setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.calibrate_the_sensors).setTabListener(this));
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure which `ActionBar`  you are using for tabs but ... just stop(as native ActionBar tabs implementation may vary on API level, also it is deprecated)  ... instead use ViewPager + TabLayout from appcompat library ...

Comment: don't use actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS). it is deprecated